# Implement back button in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-routing

I am facing issue implementing a back button feature in a ASP.NET MVC application.

This is my Home page View, for simplicity let us consider it has a div which has img element and div that renders PartialView2. PartialView2 is a partial view which generates list of tiles based on the data from the `Model`.

```
View1:
<div> remainig page content </div>
    <div>
    <img src="/path/to/img_back" id="img" />
    <div id="1">
    Html.RenderAction("PartialView2", "Home");
    </div>
    </div>
<div> remainig page content </div> 


PartialView2:
@model ICollection<Model>
@{
foreach(item in Model) {
<div class="tile">
<!-- tiles data generated using model data that I get from controller --> 
</div>
}
}
```

HomeController:

```
//field
private Stack<ICollection<Model>> myStack = new Stack<ICollection<Model>>();

public PartialViewResult GetTiles(string id) {
 var nodes = new List<Model>();
 //make a call to database and generating the list of child nodes of type Model.
 // get the rows from the db which have parentid as the passed value.
 //for back button: myStack.push(nodes);
return PartialView("PartialView2",nodes);
}

//Method to call from jQuery on click of #img
public PartialViewResult BackButton() {
return PartialView("PartialView2",myStack.Pop());
}
```

When I click on a tile, I make a call to GetTiles method in the home controller through Jquery Ajax and populate the `$("#1").html()` with the result returned from the ajax call which is the same partial view.

When I click on `#img` I call `BackButton()` method from jQuery ajax to to load html of `#1` div in the page.

Model:

```
string icon;
string title;
string parentid;
string id;
bool hasChildren;
```

With this design I only have the options to traverse the children and represent them as tiles but I need to implement a back button so as to traverse the parents. I have created a stack in the home controller and pushed the elements to the stack for each call to the `GetTiles()` method. But for every call to the controller, a new stack is instantiated. So my idea to have collection of models in the stack and on each call to back button pop the collection of `Model` and return it to the view is not working.

Can you guys please help me solve this issue? Any in-memory data structures to use to hold the parent models?
Please let me know if I need to provide further information.

Comment: Implementing "back" behaviour is typically a *client-side solution* (e.g. using Ajax for the loading of pages and something like History.js, or just HTML5 browser state management, to manipulate the browser URL). You cannot do it server-side as the page loads are stateless. You would need to use cookies or other hidden state information information (e.g. embedded in the page) to even attempt this server-side.

Comment: Thank you TrueBlueAussie for your reply. Here I am updating only a small portion of the page(only a div), can you please tell me in more detail about using browser history to get a particular div content?

Comment: Have a look at the demoes of History.js on http://balupton.github.io/history.js/demo/ It will show how you can change the browser address dynamically and respond to address changes. On older browsers it changes the address `#` bookmark instead, but `History.js` hides that implementation detail and works on all browsers.

Comment: @Neel I have started coding as there no alien attacks in New York. :)